# Intentional infinite loop in Metal shader function doesn't block the GPU

Tags: gpu, metal

I am building a **command-line tool** using Metal. I intentionally put a `for(;;)` inside my kernel function, and I expect to see the mac's display will freeze until `timeout` happens. I tried in some Metal application with a `MTLView`, and the machine got hanged.

The error message is

```
Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution.
Caused GPU Timeout Error (IOAF code 2)
```

But this doesn't happen to the command-line tool I am building. I don't know why it doesn't block the GPU. I thought all of my **threads** will keep taking the GPU resource and thus the display will freeze.

Why this is not happening?

Comment: Which Mac/GPU are you using, and which version of the OS are you running?

Comment: What code is in the loop? It's possible it was optimized away.

Comment: @ldoogy I am using Radeon 460, Mojave

Comment: @KenThomases Just simple for(;;), but it does work for sample like Hello Compute, it will get the machine hanged

Comment: And the command you're running is a compute command or a render command? Also, the command-line tool is taking a while to finish (to see if your loop is getting optimized away as @KenThomases is suggesting?)